# Plotly on_click event on Image graph object not firing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, ipython

I am trying to listen to an on click event using a plotly `go.FigureWidget` object, encapsulating a `go.Image`. I display the image by converting it to base64 jpeg (through opencv). I run the following inside a jupyter notebook;

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import numpy as np

import base64
import cv2

def image_to_jpeg(frame, to_bgr=True) -> bytes:
    frame = frame if not to_bgr else cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    _, jpeg = cv2.imencode(".jpeg", frame)
    return jpeg.tobytes()


def image_to_jpeg_b64(frame, to_bgr=True) -> bytes:
    return base64.b64encode(image_to_jpeg(frame, to_bgr=to_bgr)).decode("utf-8")

go_image = go.Image(source=f"data:image/png;base64,{image_jpeg_b64}")

def set_x(x):
    print(x) # nothing

go_image.on_click(set_x)

f = go.FigureWidget([
    go_image
])

f # in a jupyter notebook
```

I can see the image normally, but on click events are not firing ( and no print is triggered). I've also tried setting a global variable inside the `set_x` function, and this did not work as well.

[image]